# Cannot build docker images with Jenkins using ECS Fargate

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, cicd, aws-fargate

I'm using Jenkins with ECS Fargate. It works kinda nice but i have a problem that i cannot find a solution.

I have a master running on a container and it is able to launch other slave agents using also fargate.
The problem arises when I try to build docker images. Since fargate does not allow access to docker sock, daemon or any kind of root access, "docker" commands are automatically off (at least, this was what i could find out).

Some help would be really appreciated. Thanks you very much in advance!!

I tried to use kaniko, extending my Slave Agent image by copying kaniko binaries to it. On node based images it works kinda well. At least no problems so far.
When I try to build python based images or nvida/cuda images kaniko throws errors that do not occur when I perform "docker build" command on my local machine. It just works normally and creates the image. Some errors are: conflict packages during image build when apt-get install or apt-get update is used; missing system libraries even though they are listed on "dpkg --list".

I tried to launch fargate and ec2 images from my fargate master but was not able to put it to work. Not even sure if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

We are using same environment to build docker images on ECS Fargate. I think problem was Image that you use in ECS Fargate has a base image, then you try use kaniko executer the build docker image but this Dockerfile has another version of base image maybe different OS version this kind a problem for kaniko.

Try to use same base image or same OS version both ECS Fargate container image and in your Dockerfile.